# Removing an object from database and the DOM via AJAX

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, dom-manipulation

So I have this simple AJAX post request that is deleting the object from the Model as I want it to but I am struggling to delete it from the DOM correctly.

```
function removeFriend(id){

    let dataId = `${id}`

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `/delete/friend`,
        data: {
            friend_id: `${id}`,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            action: 'post'
        },
        success: function(json){
            let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
            let row = tbody.querySelector('tr[data-id=dataId]');
            console.log(row);
            row.remove();
            alert('friend has been deleted')
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}
```

I keep getting `index.js:119 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null` and the console.log(row) is showing up as null. I have tried `` let row = tbody.querySelector('tr[data-id=`${id}`]'); `` and same result.

I have tried `let row = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr[data-id=dataId]');` but then the output for console.log(row) is an empty NodeList `NodeList []` followed by `index.js:119 Uncaught TypeError: row.remove is not a function`.

This is what my table looks like:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="my_friends">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nick name</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Likes</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>lives in</th>
                <th>Remove friend</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for friend in friends %}
        <tr data-id="{{ friend.id }}">
            <td>{{friend.nick_name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.likes}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.dob | date:"Y-m-d"}}</td>
            <td>{{friend.lives_in}}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="remove-friend" name="remove-friend" value="{{ friend.id }}">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I know I have definitely assigned the data attribute correctly because I can see it showing up in my Chrome browser Elements.

Comment: Have you tried row.nodeValue = ‘’?

Comment: Try like this `tbody.querySelector('[data-id="' + dataId + '"]');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id passed to the remove friend function in the selector

```
let row = tbody.querySelector(`tr[data-id="${id}"]`);
```

Comment: This is the result: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': 'tr[data-id=15]' is not a valid selector.`

Comment: Try putting double quotes around the id

Comment: It seems the quotes are required for numeric attributes